# Installation issues of ggpubr

Tags: r, cran, ggpubr

I'm trying to install the R package `ggpubr` as follows (on Docker image) - all other libraries are installed successfully:

```
install.packages("~/mypackages/ggpubr_0.3.0.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

but I get the following error:

```
2020-06-13T08:55:43.6605261Z [0m[91mERROR: dependencies 'ggrepel', 'ggsci', 'cowplot', 'ggsignif', 'polynom', 'rstatix' are not available for package 'ggpubr'
2020-06-13T08:55:43.6608879Z [0m[91m* removing '/usr/local/R/library/ggpubr'
```

I tried to install it in different ways:

```
# Failed with the message that a mirror must be specified
install.packages("ggpubr")

# Failed due to dependencies
install.packages("ggpubr", repos="https://cran.rediris.org/")

# Failed because some dependencies cannot be installed from https://cran.rediris.org/
install.packages("ggpubr", repos="https://cran.rediris.org/", dependencies=TRUE)
```

I'm really confused. How can I fix this issue?

**Update #1:**

As suggested, I used ``:

```
install.packages("ggpubr",
                 repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/",
                 dependencies = TRUE)
```

But still got the following errors:

```
2020-06-13T10:16:21.5258238Z [0m[91mERROR: dependencies 'pbkrtest', 'lme4' are not available for package 'car'
2020-06-13T10:16:21.5258733Z [0m[91m* removing '/usr/local/R/library/car'
2020-06-13T10:16:21.8271275Z [0m[91mERROR: dependency 'car' is not available for package 'rstatix'
2020-06-13T10:16:21.8271930Z [0m[91m* removing '/usr/local/R/library/rstatix'
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2094780Z [0m[91mERROR: dependency 'rstatix' is not available for package 'ggpubr'
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2095409Z [0m[91m* removing '/usr/local/R/library/ggpubr'
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2202760Z [0m[91m
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2202943Z The downloaded source packages are in
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2203292Z    '/tmp/RtmpRJqVdH/downloaded_packages'
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2209634Z [0m[91mUpdating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2695889Z [0m[91mMaking 'packages.html' ...[0m[91m done
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2696343Z Warning messages:
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2696877Z 1: In install.packages("ggpubr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/",  :
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2697332Z   installation of package 'nloptr' had non-zero exit status
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2697747Z 2: In install.packages("ggpubr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/",  :
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2698158Z   installation of package 'lme4' had non-zero exit status
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2698562Z 3: In install.packages("ggpubr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/",  :
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2698981Z   installation of package 'pbkrtest' had non-zero exit status
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2699408Z 4: In install.packages("ggpubr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/",  :
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2699816Z  [0m[91m installation of package 'car' had non-zero exit status
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2700246Z 5: In install.packages("ggpubr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/",  :
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2700644Z   installation of package 'rstatix' had non-zero exit status
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2701086Z 6: In install.packages("ggpubr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/",  :
2020-06-13T10:16:22.2701483Z   installation of package 'ggpubr' had non-zero exit status
2020-06-13T10:16:22.8005121Z [0m[91malso installing the dependency 'triebeard'
```

**Update #2:**

Following the suggestions in comments, I tried to install dependencies one by one using `install.packages` instead of using `dependencies=TRUE`. I started with installing the package `nloptr`. Please see below the error message: `ERROR: configuration failed for package 'nloptr'`.

```
2020-06-13T11:25:07.6990004Z [91mtestopt.cpp: In function 'int test_function(int)':
2020-06-13T11:25:07.6990942Z testopt.cpp:223:21: warning: 'nlopt_result nlopt_minimize(nlopt_algorithm, int, nlopt_func_old, void*, const double*, const double*, double*, double*, double, double, double, double, const double*, int, double)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
2020-06-13T11:25:07.6991447Z      maxeval, maxtime);
2020-06-13T11:25:07.6991629Z                      ^
2020-06-13T11:25:07.6991995Z [0m[91mIn file included from testopt.cpp:44:0:
2020-06-13T11:25:07.6992273Z ../api/nlopt.h:329:28: note: declared here
2020-06-13T11:25:07.6992503Z  NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_minimize(
2020-06-13T11:25:07.6992740Z                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-06-13T11:25:07.8309097Z [0mmv -f .deps/testopt.Tpo .deps/testopt.Po
2020-06-13T11:25:07.8351821Z /bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++11  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -I/usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/build/80754af9/r-base_1570124924484/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix   -o testopt testfuncs.o testopt.o ../libnlopt_cxx.la -lm 
2020-06-13T11:25:07.8924933Z [91mlibtool: link: warning: library `/usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libstdc++.la' was moved.
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9019996Z [0m[91mlibtool: link: warning: library `/usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libstdc++.la' was moved.
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9146941Z [0mlibtool: link: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++11 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -I/usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/build/80754af9/r-base_1570124924484/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -o .libs/testopt testfuncs.o testopt.o  ../.libs/libnlopt_cxx.so /usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libstdc++.so -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/tmp/RtmpWCPONP/R.INSTALL11b11c1011f6/nloptr/src/nlopt_src/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib/../lib
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9602105Z [91m/usr/local/envs/mlopspython_ci/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin[0m[91m/ld: ../.libs/libnlopt_cxx.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9602657Z collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9621958Z [0m[91mmake[2]: *** [Makefile:381: testopt] Error 1
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9622950Z [0mmake[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpWCPONP/R.INSTALL11b11c1011f6/nloptr/src/nlopt_src/test'
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9633779Z [91mmake[1]: *** [Makefile:574: all-recursive] Error 1
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9634679Z [0mmake[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpWCPONP/R.INSTALL11b11c1011f6/nloptr/src/nlopt_src'
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9635296Z [91mmake: *** [Makefile:438: all] Error 2
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9838980Z [0m[91mERROR: configuration failed for package 'nloptr'
2020-06-13T11:25:07.9845313Z [0m[91m* removing '/usr/local/R/library/nloptr'
```

Comment: @MarcoSandri: It looks like all these packages are interdependent. I get errors: `ERROR: dependency 'car' is not available for package 'rstatix'`

Comment: @MarcoSandri: According to my understanding, `rstatix` should be installed when I run `install.packages(c('nloptr','lme4','pbkrtest','rstatix','car'))`. But for some reason I'm getting dependency errors. It looks like there should be a specific sequence to install them.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem
After install nloptr, it worked.
nloptr also needs you to install cmake
so run at terminal

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

And then install nloptr

```
install.packages("nloptr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a CRAN mirror that is able to provide all the packages, e.g.

```
install.packages("ggpubr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies = TRUE)
```

(This works at least for me.)

Or you can define `repos` as a vector of CRAN mirrors:

```
install.packages("ggpubr",
                 repos = c("https://cran.rediris.org/", "https://cloud.r-project.org/"),
                 dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check this CRAN mirror.

Comment: I got the same errors... and I don't understand why it happens. It says `ERROR: dependency 'rstatix' is not available for package 'ggpubr'`. But I checked that `rstatix` is available in `https://cloud.r-project.org`.

Comment: Which version of R do you use?

Comment: @Fluxy I have R 4.0.1...  You run your commands on a Docker image, can there be some network problem, blocking some requests etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I am installing many libraries and only have issue with `ggpubr`. Therefore it does not seem to be the network issue. Please check my Update #2. I tried to install one of dependencies (`nloptr`) and got the error `ERROR: configuration failed for package 'nloptr'`. I don't know how to fix this configuration error and why does it occur.

Comment: @Fluxy Wow, that's so strange! I have found something similar about `nloptr` on [GitHub issues](https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr/issues/51), maybe installing the suggested `libnlopt-dev` library could help? And I have found some other suggestion about updating R packages on [factoextra](https://github.com/kassambara/factoextra/issues/65) and [ggpubr](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/75) itself. What Docker image do you use? Can you provide your `sessionInfo()` from R please?

Comment: It's Debian and R 3.6.0. Ok, let me check these links.

Comment: Your indications helped. Thanks.

Comment: @Fluxy Great! Thanks for your feedback, I'm so glad it works for you! It seemed so strange for me... What was the real cause of your problem in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer of [NMostajo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6478387/nmostajo) installing `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` because the installation problem of `ggpubr` seemed to be caused by problems with `nloptr`. This alone did not fix the problem. On github I found another [hint](https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr/issues/21) that one needs to also install `libnlopt-dev`. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in R, but I had to install couple of packages and also had to install few dependencies in R. Here is what I did.

In terminal run

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev gfortran
rm -r /home/isuru/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/00LOCK-RcppEigen
```

Then install packages in R

```
install.packages("pbkrtest")
install.packages("ggpubr")
```

I also followed some of the instructions in other answers. So quite not sure what is needed exactly. I was using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install gcc-fortran or equivalent package for your system

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and followed @ad_bek 's advice, that alone didn't solve it, but gave me a more informative error during the installation in R,

`missing: libcurl4-openssl-dev`

After installing `libcurl4-openssl-dev` in the system the `install.packages("ggpubr")` was working in R

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the installation of libnlopt-dev solved the problem.
System: Ubuntu 22.04 and RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554
Ciao